# How to get user's name rather than id from same table in Postgresql subquery?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a users table:
with fields like:
firstname, last_name..., manager_id...,

manager_id is just the id of another user.

When I run the query:

```
   SELECT DISTINCT ON(users.id) user.id, CONCAT(users.first_name, ' ', users.last_name) AS \
                'employee', users.email, \
                (SELECT manager_id), \
                (SELECT users.first_name from users where users.id = manager_id) as Manager,\
                (SELECT DISTINCT to_char(auth_user.last_login, 'Mon dd, yyyy')) as Last_Login FROM users INNER JOIN auth_user ON (users.user_id = auth_user.id)
```

This query `(SELECT manager_id)` returns the manager's id, however the next line

> `(SELECT users.first_name from users where users.id = manager_id) as
>   Manager`

returns blank.
I also tried joining the table on itself which only returns the name of 1 manager:

> `(SELECT e.first_name FROM employees_employee e INNER JOIN
>   employees_employee s ON s.id = e.coach_id limit 1)`

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql?

Comment: It looks like your table is being referenced by 'users' in both cases. I would try to add an alias for the manager lookup, as in 'users AS u2'.

Comment: @terminus Postgresql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because no users are their own managers.  *Always* qualify your column names!

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (u.id) u.id,
       CONCAT(u.first_name, ' ', u.last_name) AS employee
       u.email,
       u.manager_id,
       (SELECT u2.first_name FROM users u2 where u2.id = u.manager_id) as Manager,
       to_char(au.last_login, 'Mon dd, yyyy') as Last_Login
FROM users u INNER JOIN
     auth_user au
     ON u.user_id = au.id
ORDER BY u.user_id;
```

Comment: Worked as expected. Thanks!